# How to run AndroidTests with a dummy database

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, android-testing

Let me see if I can explain well.. A lot of my UI depends on data from the [local Room database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). I'm running some androidTests on my UI only to find that it has no data, so there isn't really much to test. In order to test that my UI is working as expected, it seems like I need to set up a dummy database with dummy data for the androidTest directory.

For example, one activity is a list of items from the database that the user would've created while using the app. When I go to create tests for it though that list of items is empty.

Can someone point me in the right direction to set up a dummy database?

Answer (score -1):

Room is a wrapper around SQLite. An SQLite database consists of 1-3 files which can be copied to wherever (between devices not only Android but basically any device e.g. Windows PC/Macs).

As such if you have a populated database then you can copy it to wherever.

The above mentions 1-3 files. The core database is a single file. The other files are logging files.

There are 2 primary logging modes Journal and WAL, the latter being the mode that Room will use by default.

With Journal mode data is applied to the database and written to the log, enabling changes to be rolled back. There is no need for the journal file (the database file name suffixed with `-journal`). So just the single database file can be copied.

With WAL mode (**W**rite **A**head **L**ogging) changes are written to the **-wal** file and at times then written to the actual database file. Thus if the **-wal** file contains data it is part of the entire database. The 3rd file is the **-shm** file which is a -wal file for the -wal file. As such if the **-wal** file is **not empty then all 3 files MUST be copied**.

You may wish to have a look at

- https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html (WAL)
  and/or
- https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html (WAL and JOURNAL)

If using devices via Android Studio then you can use `Device Explorer` to move/copy files between devices *(if permissions permit, they will on emulated devices)*.